# Ошибка "Свойство Connection не инициализировано"

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, sql

В чем суть: пишу собственный класс-провайдер для работы с БД, но возникает ошибка.

```
namespace Tourism.Data.Providers
{
    public class DatabaseProvider
    {
    // Common database stuff
    public DbConnection Connection;
    public string ConnectionString = "Data Source=CRUST\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Tourism;Integrated Security=True";
    public bool ConnectionOpened;
    public string Query;

    public void Connect(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
        Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        Connection.Open();
        if (Connection.State.ToString() == "Open")
            ConnectionOpened = true;
        else
            ConnectionOpened = false;
    }

    public void SQLWithoutFetch(string query)
    {
        if (!ConnectionOpened)
            Connect(ConnectionString);
        Query = query;
        using (Connection)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Bad SQL query");
            }
        }
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

При выполнении строки `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` возникает ошибка

> ExecuteNonQuery: Свойство Connection не инициализировано

Подключение к БД идет, о чем сигнализирует `MessageBox` с выписанным в него `Connection.State.ToString();`.

Пробовал такие пути решения:

- проводить полный коннект внутри метода `SQLWithoutFetch`
- изменять запрос к БД (мой нынешний - "USE Places;")
- пробовал делать класс-синглтон и статику

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: public static void Connect(string connectionString)??

Comment: Попробовал, не помогло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При создании `SqlConnection` необходимо явно указывать поле `Connection`, иначе оно автоматически [инициализируется в `null`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sebfsz50.aspx)

Честно говоря, я не знаю, почему `API` позволяет конструировать невалидные объекты, но думаю, что это не `design flaw`, а все-таки служит какой-то цели.

**В вашем случае нужно использовать:**

```
var command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
```

---

Кстати, да. `SqlConnection` - это `IDisposable`. Соответственно, если вы храните его как поле в вашем классе, то не обходимо делать класс `IDisposable` и предоставлять методы для освобождения ресурсов *(иначе в ближайшем будущем вы можете столкнуться с проблемами).*

Более простой вариант - использовать `connection` в локальном скоупе через `using`.

---

**Ваш текущий вариант с `using` неправильный, т.к произойдет следующее:**

- В методе `Connect` будет создан объект `Connection`.
- После первого вызова метода `SQLWithoutFetch` (на выходе из `using` блока) будет неявно вызван `Connection.Dispose()`.
- При любой следующей попытке вызвать `SQLWithoutFetch` вы (в лучшем случае) получите `ObjectDisposedException`, поскольку объект был освобожден в предыдущем вызове.

*Как решать это я написал выше.*

---

**Еще одно замечание:**

```
catch (SqlException)
{
    throw new Exception("Bad SQL query");
}
```

Заменять конкретный `SqlException` с параметрами ошибки на общий `Exception`  недопустимо. `try-catch` здесь вообще не нужен, т.к вы не можете ничего сделать внутри этого метода, чтобы исправить ошибочную ситуацию.

**Обработка ошибок должна быть уровнем выше, следовательно, автоматически проброшенный `SqlException` - это хорошо.**

---

**А, и еще:**

```
if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) ...
```

Comment: я через using (Connection) и написал
по поводу var command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection) - эта конструкция подчеркивается у меня как ошибка, причем описание говорит, что у меня неправильно заданы аргументы

Comment: Вы объявили `Connection` как `DbConnection`, а нужно явно указать, что тип переменной - `SqlConnection`: `public SqlConnection Connection;`

Comment: @Indenk Использовать супертипы где возможно - это, конечно, хорошо, но не в этом случае, поскольку `SqlCommand` не может быть сконструирован с помощью произвольного `DbConnection`.

Comment: спасибо огромное, завелось :)

Comment: @Indenk Посмотрите обновления ответа по поводу `using` и исключения и сравнения `enum'ов`.